# Как лучше сделать динамическую ссылку на SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

У SQLite есть версии для x86 и x64. Компьютеры и Windows у нас тоже есть разные. Нужно, чтобы всё работало и собиралось на компьютерах разных разработчиков с разными CPU.

Пока что у меня есть только такое решение: не ссылаться из сборок на SQLite, а загружать сборки динамически в зависимости от CPU, а для вызова свойств и методов использовать тип dynamic. Но это как-то криво выглядит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any CPU не катит по описаным автором причинам. Я использовал кусок кода в самом файле проекта (*.csproj), который в зависимости от архитектуры CPU добавляет ссылку нужной разрядности. Проект найти не могу, но что то типа такого:

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition="$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE) == 'AMD64' Or $(PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432) == 'AMD64'" />
    <Otherwise>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139, processorArchitecture=x86">
          <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
          <HintPath>..\..\Lib\SQLite\x86\System.Data.SQLite.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
```

То есть по умолчанию добавляется например ссылка на х86 и небольшое условие, которое обновит сссылку на другую, если необходимо. В примере только наоборот.

Answer (score 2):

Экстремальное решение - перейти с SQLite на [C#-SQLite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/). В этом случае, проблемы x32-x64 уже не будут актуальны.

Answer (score 1):

А почему нельзя использовать вариант Any CPU? Или х86 всегда, ведь х64 достаточно сносно работают с х86

**UPD**
Приходилось работать с библиотекой System.Data.SQLite.dll (x86) тестировал и на х64 и на х86.
Правда была какая то проблема, не помню уже, разрешилась дописанием одной строчки в app.config

Comment: А чем это поможет? У моего соседа система x64, у меня x86. Если подцепить сборку для x86, не работает у него, если x64 - у меня. Проблема в том, что требуются ссылки на разные версии SQLite.

Comment: Давайте вспоминайте.